# Why am I not able to share my webpage link on Facebook?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The code looks fine to me, but I have no clue why is it not bringing up the FB popup and sharing my site.

here is the js part

```
function streamPublish(name, description, hrefTitle, hrefLink, userPrompt){
          FB.ui(
          {
              method: 'stream.publish',
              message: '',
              attachment: {
                  name: name,
                  caption: '',
                  description: (description),
                  href: hrefLink
              },
              action_links: [
                  { text: hrefTitle, href: hrefLink }
              ],
              user_prompt_message: userPrompt
          },
          function(response) {

          });

      }
      function showStream(){
          FB.api('/me', function(response) {
              //console.log(response.id);
              streamPublish(response.name, 'Connect with Abhishek Raj Simon on his new website http://abhisheksimion.cjb.net', 'hrefTitle', 'http://abhisheksimion.cjb.net', "Share abhisheksimion.cjb.net");
          });
      }
```

html

```
<a id="fbanchor" href="#" onclick="showStream(); return false;">Like it, Share it!</a>
```

Can somebody point out, where am i going wrong? You can visit the work in progress website http://abhisheksimion.cjb.net

Comment: Curious, did you consider using FBML? It has support for sharing, and if you add opengraph metatags to your site, Facebook will properly parse and show information that you care about.

Comment: @Alan: FB is in the process of deprecating FBML see here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/ any other alternative?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I meant to say, if you simply want to share your page via facebook, use the sharer.php: example: http://www.inrixtraffic.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a javascript error:

> Error: showStream is not defined
>   Source File:
>   http://users.cjb.net/abhisheksimion/
>   Line: 1

I think in your script tag, line 128, that closing bracket should be higher, to close off the `fqlQuery()` function. As written, `showStream()` is part of the `fqlQuery()` function, which causes `showStream()` to fail.

If all you are trying to do is add basic facebook functionality like "Like" and "Share" this can be achieved without using heavy javascript.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?yoursite.com

Where 'yoursite.com' is the site you want to share. You can use opengraph tags to specify the content.

Comment: @Alan: Thanks, that was 1 of the problems.. So i removed it. But still I am not able get the popup. Apart from sharing I also want some other features eg: like button, users will be able to post messages to their account so its not just sharing :) . Also incase you could not find the problem with it, can you tell me how did you find that the error occured at line 128, so that i'll try looking for 1 myself. Thanks

Comment: If you use firefox, open up the Tools->Error Console. Clear it, and reload the page. It will show you any errors you have, when you attempt to do anything on the page. As for line 128, I just visually inspected your script.

Comment: I just checked your site, and I clicked the link, and I got the pop-up. Are you sure you have javascript enabled, and aren't running any popup blockers?

Comment: Looks like he's fixed it since he posted the question.

Comment: @Alan,@echeese: Ya the popup is coming now, my net speed was very slow that time, and after sometime I checked my connection was gone, so may be that's why after i corrected, I could not find the difference. Thanks all for your help :)

Comment: Most likely you just had the page cached locally in your browser. When doing web development, it's beneficial to clear your browser cache frequently.